# Setting the LOGGING__CONSOLE__FORMATTERNAME in aspnet6.0 image

Tags: docker, containers, .net-6.0

How do I set this environment variable when I run a .NET 6.0 docker file?

I have a docker image based off aspnet6.0 Docker file. By default the environment variable is set as Json. I want to set it to Simple without changing the code.

The console log formatter is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter

Can this be done?

I thought it would as simple as:

```
docker run --env LOGGING__CONSOLE__FORMATTERNAME=Simple <CONTAINER_NAME>
```

This does set an environment variable with this name. However it does not overwrite the environment variable it results in a duplicate setting. I would expect making the above command to overwrite the setting for: `LOGGING__CONSOLE__FORMATTERNAME`.

Therefore my console is still formatted as JSON and not in Simple format as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is it not overriding the setting is the capitalisation should match the existing environment variable: `Logging__Console__FormatterName`

However the Docker container `dotnet/aspnet` has now reverted to the behaviour in 5.0 by not overriding the log format to JSON.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/containers/6.0/console-formatter-default